# Depth of testing?

Tags: android

I have a fairly basic application. I'm loading it up on 2.1+ on emulators and 2.3.3 on an n1 and basically just making sure everything looks right and does what it's supposed to.

I was reading about activity testing on the dev site and it talks about creating test applications and such. I don't get the point of testing whether a textview = a resource string that you set it to or not.

How deep do you really need to test fairly basic apps before letting other people use them. Is there really anything that I won't catch using emulators and an n1 that test applications and such will?

Comment: What kind of resources is your application using? The more you use the better you need to test. (internet, camera, gyroscope, trackball) Also, what is minimum version you have set in your manifest? Did you test on that version (are you using newer APIs?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is test anything that is complex enough to go wrong. If you don't have alternate resources, it is generally too simple to break.

Answer (score 1):

Creating programs to test other programs? The only purpose I would see to this would be testing security of your app.

I've never had to create anything like this, and I publish many types of apps on the marketplace.

In my opinion, it is always best to do testing on an actual phone. Emulators arnt fully functional and possibly slower than the phone itself.

Comment: This has been common in complex development for decades, and recently became known as Test Driven Development. If you have a large codebase, it becomes impractical to manually test applications after every change, so automated tests help you discover bugs before users do, and to capture bugs that may overlooked through UI testing. Of course, whether or not it is worth doing very much depends on context - it means writing more code, but reduces time spent revisiting code after weeks, months, or years, working on something else.